# C minimum function always returning 2686916

Tags: c, arrays, function, min

I am doing a simple function that returns the minimum integer from numbers given from the user(array).

However, it always print `2686916` at the end. Here is my code:

```
int function()
{
    int ar[100];
    int i;
    int smallest = INT_MAX;
    int nums;
    int num;
    int sum=0;
    printf("\nenter array size\n");

    scanf("%d",&num);
    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&ar[i]);
        sum=sum+ar[i];
    }
    if (nums <smallest){
        smallest=nums;
        printf("the smallest %d\n,smallest);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You have not set `nums` before you check its value, and you would have known this if you heeded compiler warnings. And `2686916` is not the max int, as the tiniest research would have shown you. `smallest` was set to the max int value.

Comment: Not only all that, your function doesn't even return the minimum, and again, the compiler tells you that. It either returns `0` or an undefined value.

Comment: Ok first I meant it doesnt print.I want it just to print the mininum integer,not return it.and it keeps printing 2686916 at the end.INT_MAX is linked to the "smallest" variable so its the same thing I meant.I dont know how to fix that while keeping the array loop im doing.thank you

Comment: And how about all the other things? In particular `nums` is never set. Please address all the comments. And  your code doesn't compile anyway (last `printf` has unterminated string) so please fix that up too.

Comment: But I dont know how to fix it because I have to manage the loop that make able to input the right numbers of integers(array size) and also the function that check if its smaller than smallest.I really dont know how to do this.and my code compile perfectly fine with codeblocks

Comment: This code is so far from functional I think you need to look away and think about what you are trying to do. For example the loop makes no attempt at finding the smallest value. It needs more than a little debug breath on it, sorry.

Comment: Should use `if (ar[i] <=smallest){` within the loop.  Use `return 0;` outside the `if`

Comment: I tried it and it still doesnt work; could you modify my code to show what you mean? thanks @chux

Comment: With code `int nums; ...  if (nums <smallest){ smallest=nums;`, what is the uninitialized `nums` supposed to do?

Comment: @sageb. modify your question to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

My friend, it seems you are new to C, and before you ask questions like this one you should try to follow some tutorials for C. You might try something like [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/).

If the question you ask is not clear or the code you post won't compile anyway it is very hard to help you out. For now this is all I can do:

```
int function()
{
   int ar[100];
   int i;
   int smallest = INT_MAX;
   int nums = 0; //Always Initialize your variables!
   int num = 0;
   int sum= 0;
   printf("\nenter array size\n");

  scanf("%d",&num);
  for(i=0;i<num;i++)
  {
    scanf("%d",&ar[i]);
    sum=sum+ar[i];
  }
  if (nums <smallest)
  {
    smallest=nums;
    printf("the smallest %d\n",smallest);
  }
    return 0; //Don't put this in a place that might not be executed!
}
```

Now it should at least compile, it still doesn't do anything useful as far as I can see. You compare "nums", a variable you didn't use before, with the biggest value of an int, set it to the never used "nums" and print it.

You might want use "sums" or "ar[i]" in the if statement instead, and printing one of these values.(still not 100% sure what you want to do).

Some tips for next time (before you ask a question!):

- Variables should always be initialized

In your code you try to use the value of "nums" before it gets a value, this might cause errors or strange results in your code.

- Don't put  a return in a place that might be skipped,

In your code, "nums" would be bigger than "smallest" (unlikely, bit for example), the code would skip the if statement and never reach the return.

- Read your compiler warnings

The code you posted can't compile, read your errors and warnings, and fix them.

- (tip) Use better variable names, using names like nums, num and sum make it easy to overlook a mistake.